# Spring WebserviceTemplate uses JMS as messageSender

Tags: java, spring, jms, webservicetemplate

In one of the projects I worked on the architect used Spring WebserviceTemplate in most of the backend services and its definition in xml config is like:

```
<bean id="someservice" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
  <property name="messageSender">
    <bean class="JmsMessageSender">
....
```

In this configuration, the JmsMessageSender (`org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.JmsMessageSender`) extends WebserviceMessageSender  and its underlying infrastructure is Solace the message broker.

As I understand that the webservice is for synchronous communication, the above should be using the JMS request/response model only - there is no way to use Spring's WebserviceTemplate for JMS's asynchronous model.

Is it correct? However if we start a new project for a similar purpose, wouldn't it be better to use the more simple and elegant RestfulTemplate+Json+Jackson, as opposed to SOAP+JAXB solution as above?